# How to keep "spaces" although dict contains it?

Tags: python, join, dictionary, append

i am simply trying to read from a file encrypt and display it.

And I want to display the result word by word, but somehow spaces are removed (my dict also contains ' ':' ') and result text is displayed without spaces.

For example,

**aa bb cc** is what i read from file,

Current **Output** is **ffggğğ**, but i want it as **ff gg ğğ**

...please help...

```
monocrypt = {
    'a': 'f',
    'b': 'g',
    'c': 'ğ',
    'ç': 'h',
    'd': 'ı',
    'e': 'i',
    'f': 'j',
    'g': 'k',
    'ğ': 'l',
    'h': 'm',
    'ı': 'n',
    'i': 'o',
    'j': 'ö',
    'k': 'p',
    'l': 'r',
    'm': 's',
    'n': 'ş',
    'o': 't',
    'ö': 'u',
    'p': 'ü',
    'r': 'v',
    's': 'y',
    'ş': 'z',
    't': 'a',
    'u': 'b',
    'ü': 'c',
    'v': 'ç',
    'y': 'd',
    'z': 'e',
    ' ': ' ',
}

inv_monocrypt = {}
for key, value in monocrypt.items():
    inv_monocrypt[value] = key

f = open("C:\\Hobbit.txt","r")
print("Reading file...")

message = f.read()
crypt = ''.join(i for i in message if i.isalnum())
encrypted_message = []
for letter in crypt:
    encrypted_message.append(monocrypt[letter.lower()])

print(''.join(encrypted_message))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're dropping all the whitespace at this step

```
crypt = ''.join(i for i in message if i.isalnum())
```

So leave them all in there. Use `dict.get` with the default argument to preserve letters that aren't keys

```
crypt = f.read()
encrypted_message = []
for letter in crypt:
    encrypted_message.append(monocrypt.get(letter.lower(), letter.lower()) )
```

If you really just want to preserve spaces (and not punctuation/other whitespace etc)

```
message = f.read()
crypt = ''.join(i for i in message if i.lower() in monocrypt)
encrypted_message = []
for letter in crypt:
    encrypted_message.append(monocrypt[letter.lower()])
```

You can simplify a little like this

```
message = f.read().lower()
crypt = ''.join(i for i in message if i in monocrypt)
encrypted_message = [monocrypt[letter] for letter in crypt]
```

Comment: Thank you Mr. Rooy, its really helpful..and solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it works as intended since I don't have hobbit.txt but I made a small rewrite to make the code a little simpler. It should also solve your problem.

```
monocrypt = {
    'a': 'f',
    'b': 'g',
    'c': 'ğ',
    'ç': 'h',
    'd': 'ı',
    'e': 'i',
    'f': 'j',
    'g': 'k',
    'ğ': 'l',
    'h': 'm',
    'ı': 'n',
    'i': 'o',
    'j': 'ö',
    'k': 'p',
    'l': 'r',
    'm': 's',
    'n': 'ş',
    'o': 't',
    'ö': 'u',
    'p': 'ü',
    'r': 'v',
    's': 'y',
    'ş': 'z',
    't': 'a',
    'u': 'b',
    'ü': 'c',
    'v': 'ç',
    'y': 'd',
    'z': 'e',
    ' ': ' ',
}

with open("hobbit.txt") as hobbitfile:
    file_text = hobbitfile.read()

crypted_message = ""

for char in file_text:
    char = char.lower()
    if char in monocrypt:
        crypted_message += monocrypt[char]
    else:
        #I don't know if you want to add the other chars as well.
        #Uncomment the next line if you do.
        #crypted_message += str(char)
        pass

print(crypted_message)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the docs :
http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalnum

isalnum drops your whitespaces.

use this if you want to preserve the space characters, everything else stays the same :

```
crypt = ''.join(i for i in message if i.isalnum() or i==' ')
```

If you want to preserve all whitespaces, do this :

```
crypt = ''.join(i for i in message if i.isalnum() or i.isspace())
```